# Clip image to drawing area

Tags: graphics, miktex

I have a vector graphic that I need to include in a LaTeX file. Since LaTeX doesn't support SVG, I attempted to include it as a PDF. The problem is, that there are some elements of the image that exceed the actual drawing area and should not be displayed. Those elements are not cut off by LaTeX but rather taken as part of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{drawing.pdf}

\end{document}
```

with [this drawing.pdf](http://filebin.net/11c9lc89bh) results in
[image: The resulting LaTeX document]

How can I tell LaTeX to only include the canvas area of the PDF?
When I open drawing.pdf with my PDF reader, I see the image clipped the way I would expect.

**Edit:** Apparently this issue does not come up using *texlive*, but only using *MiKTeX*.

Comment: There's a `bb` option to `\includegraphics`, but that requires you to specify the bounding box coordinates by hand.

Comment: You can use Inkscape to edit the SVG file if you wish.

Comment: add clip to the options (or use \includegraphics*)

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I can't do that, since I don't know the exact size of the parts of the drawing that exceed the image area.

Comment: @Sigur: I want to avoid that. Also, I didn't really expect this to be a problem so, even though this is a viable workaround for few images, there should be a way without it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I tried both, but it didn't do anything for me.

Comment: If I use the linked pdf with the posted docuemnt with texlive 2013 pdflatex only `ceeding the im` shows, there is no overlap. What system are you using (unlike EPS it's rather hard I think to make a pdf that over-runs its stated area)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I use Windows with MiKTeX.

I also tried it under Ubuntu with texlive now and you are right, this doesn't happen there. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @schtreber none at all:-) you could add \listfiles to the document and check if you have a later version of pdftex.def but I suspect it is a difference in the pdftex executable, maybe a different version of the pdf library, you probably need to ask on a miktex specific list (I don't have miktex to try)

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using? Have you tried a different PDF viewer?

Comment: @Heiko: I have. It's definitely not the PDF viewer.

Comment: @schtreber: Which versions do you use? With `\listfiles` you get a version list in the `.log` file. How do you compile the `.tex` file (pdflatex, xelatex, ...)? Can you put the result somewhere?

Comment: Voted unclear: the problem is not reproducible and without `\listfiles` output we have no hope of diagnosing.